# Requirements for becoming a baker

Tags: baking, baker, staking

I just want to know the requirements for baking. Or becoming a baker. I've only been invested in tables for seven or eight months I like it's everything about it and I want to be able to someday possibly be a baker provided obviously I know the requirements and how much I need to be invested whether it be time or money.

Comment: Setup questions about baking infrastructures are better answered in other community channels such as riot or telegram and the dedicated tezos baking slack

Answer (score 2):

It takes a minimum of 8K Tez (*not tezzies) to start self-baking. You will also need a fair amount of linux command-line experience, as there is no GUI. There is the 3rd party toolset, Kiln, but it is still command-line setup (Kiln also requires additional CPU/RAM).

Your computer running the node and baking software only needs 2 CPUs (virtual or cores) and about 4GB RAM. Anything above this will sit idle (Kiln requires additional CPU/RAM as stated above). An SSD is required, about 30GB right now, growing less than 1GB/month. It also needs to be online 24/7. You can bake using VPS in the cloud, or a computer at your house. A ledger device is most secure for key management, but not required; you can still bake securely with encrypted keys.

You will need to spend a couple hours each week looking things over. You should understand how the basic Tezos protocol works for debugging issues like missed bakes and endorsements. There are dedicated baker chat channels you can join too for direct help.